# jQuery $.get returns 403 from physical client site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

This is the strangest thing, only from my clients physical location is this occurring. I'm performing server-side validation using $.get jQuery function, for three form sections within a single larger form. After each section the $.get calls the PHP validation script. Only at the client physical site does the script return a 403 error on the third and last validation call - the first two process fine. I can also run through the entire form from other locations using various browsers IE8+, Chrome, FF, Windows, Mac without any issues.

I haven't pinned it, but I have a hunch it is something to do with the site internal domain being similar to the external domain, with the exception of .local for local and .com for external. I've used the FQDN when calling $.get, and still get the error.

I have isolated the issue to a array variable being passed to the $.get - which makes no sense to me, I've tried changing all the values within the variable and even the variable names etc.

The *services_explain_array* array is what is causing the issue when added to the *finish_array*, when left out everything works as expected.

**UPDATE**

When checking the network debug on FF, the third and final $.get call returns from an unknown server "GoAhead WebServer", instead of my actual web server which is "Apache"

---

```
    //SET OTHER SERVICES REQUIREMENTS
var services_other_required;
if ($('#otherservices').prop('checked') === true) {
    services_other_required = 'required';
} else {
    services_other_required = '';
}

//CREATE ELEMENT ARRAYS
//GET ALL SERVICES INPUT ELEMENTS THAT ARE CHECKED AND ADD THEM TO AN ARRAY 
var services_checked_array = [];
$("#services_method input").each(function (index, value) {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
        services_checked_array.push($(this).data("display"));
    }
});

//CONVERT INPUT ELEMENTS FROM ARRAY TO STRING TO BE VALIDATED
var services_val = services_checked_array.join(', ');

//CREATE ELEMENT ARRAYS
var services_array = new Array('services', services_val, 'alphnum', 'required');
var services_explain_array = new Array('servicesexp', $('#servicesexp').val(), 'alphnum', services_other_required);
var delivery_array = new Array('delivery', $('#delivery').val(), 'word', 'required');
var additional_array = new Array('additional', $('#additional').val(), 'alphnum');

//CREATE SECTION ARRAY
var finish_array = new Array(services_array, delivery_array, additional_array);

validate(finish_array, 'finish', 'summary');
```

---

```
function validate(validation_array, current_section, next_section){ 
$.get("order/validate.php", {'input_array' : validation_array}, 
function(data){ /** LOTS'o'Stuff HERE **/ }, 'JSON'); }
```

Comment: `403` is forbidden. check permissions. what do you get when you try to manually call the PHP validation script.

Comment: Yeah - I don't think its a permissions issue. If it was, why does it work 95% of the time? and why is adding this jQuery array to the $.get data causing it to return this? I'm adding some more detail to the description, there is some more information that may be helpful

Comment: how are you using the array at `$.get`?

Comment: Added second code snippet - it never makes it into the function(data), dies when making the $.get

Comment: I think you need `JSON.stringify(validation_array)`. `$.get` data can be `A plain object or string`

Comment: I've actually tried that too - I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Try `/order/validate.php`. Relative paths are relative to the current URL. By putting a slash in-front of the path you are calling the file from the root.

Comment: another suggestion is use full url `/order/validate.php` if folder order is in site root or `./order/validate.php`

Comment: neither `/order/validate.php` nor `./order/validation.php` worked. I've also used the FQDN.

Comment: what is the output of `order/validate.php?input_array=sometext`? from browser

Comment: `null` is the output of order/validate.php?input_array=sometext

Comment: almost giving-up. one last try. are you including any additional file when you need to validate `services_explain_array`?

Comment: That that I know of, `var services_explain_array = new Array('servicesexp', $('#servicesexp').val(), 'alphnum', services_other_required);` -- something in this array is causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you see "GoAhead Web Server", you are probably talking to the embedded router in your network WIFI gateway or switch.